# Unable to create a file in Docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a Docker image for running code in a sandbox, I want to create a file by providing env variable as a url and using curl to download and executing it.

```
FROM gcc:4.9
WORKDIR /usr/src/
CMD curl ${CODE_FILE} -o code.c
CMD gcc -o myapp code.c
cmd ./myapp
```

It looks like file is not been created
Error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./myapp: not found
```

Comment: You only get one `CMD`; if you have multiples, only the last one has an effect.  You need to `COPY` your application code in and `RUN` the compiler.

Comment: @d_kennetz the output is given as error

Comment: @mr.blue - David has given you the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks you're confusing `CMD` and `RUN`.

- [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) allows executing steps during the Docker image build phase, aka *layers*.
- [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) allows to provide defaults for an executing container and can include executables as well.

Given this, this is your refactored `Dockerfile`

```
FROM gcc:4.9

WORKDIR /usr/src/
RUN curl ${CODE_FILE} -o code.c \
    && gcc -o myapp code.c

CMD [./myapp]
```